# How to move connectionString from App.config to code in C#?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I want to remove connectionString from App.config and add it to code. I'm using WinForms(C#) and .Net Framework 4.8. I have textBoxes and a datagridview on my form. I'm using Microsoft Access Database (.mdb). I want to do this because database's password is visible in App.config. Is there any way to do that

Here is my app.config XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Locker.Properties.Settings.pw_dbConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\files\pw_db.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XYZ"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to keep a connection string in code. let us know why do you want to mode it to code?

Comment: So that another user can not get the database's password and open my .mdb file. I'm making a password manager.

Comment: Ask the user for the password at runtime when they want to open the DB, not save it anywhere. Then you can build the connection string on the fly.

Comment: Password-protected MS Access files as trivial to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to define the connection string in code, better you can encrypt it in the app.config file.

Please follow the following steps:

- Rename app.config to web.config
- Open command prompt and type:
  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef
  "connectionStrings" path of the web.config>
- Rename web.config back to app.config

If you open the file in notepad, you will see the encrypted value and you can continue using it as you were using before.

Comment: I had encrypted app.config,  but I was searching its alternative also.

Comment: What alternative?. If you strict at defining it in code, then you can simply use string variable and assign it, but again I'm not suggesting it